# ui-select f.selected is undefined

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I am trying to ui-select in my app >.< It is giving me soo much trouble.  I have followed the examples and docs and I cannot understand what I am doing wrong here.

This is my html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label small">User Roles</label>
    <ui-select multiple ng-model="vm.form.roles" ng-disabled="disabled">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Select roles">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="role.id as role in vm.roles | filter:$select.search">
            {{role.name}}
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
</div>
```

This is my controller:

```
angular.module('app.ctrls')
    .controller('UsersCtrl', UsersCtrl);

// Injecting Dependencies
UsersCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'Role', 'User'];

// Controller Function
function UsersCtrl($scope, $state, $stateParams, $r, $u) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.form = {};
    vm.form.roles = [];
    vm.users = [];
    vm.roles = [];

    vm.messageBag = [];
    vm.errorBag = [];

    vm.getAllRoles = function() {
        $r.get()
            .success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
                vm.messageBag = response.messages;
                vm.roles = response.data;
                for (var i = 0; i < vm.messageBag.length; i++) {
                    $scope.createToast('success', vm.messageBag[i]);
                }
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                // Clearing Error Bag
                vm.errorBag = [];

                for (var prop in data) {
                    if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                        data[prop].forEach(function (msg) {
                            if (vm.errorBag.indexOf(msg) == -1) {
                                vm.errorBag.push(msg);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < vm.errorBag.length; i++) {
                    $scope.createToast('danger', vm.errorBag[i]);
                }
            });
    };


    // Controller Initialiser
    vm.init = function() {
        //
    };

    // Initialising Controller
    vm.init();

}
```

This is the error I get in my console whenever I load the page:

> Error: f.selected is undefined
>   f.getPlaceholder@http://admin.xxxxxx.app/scripts/lazyload/select.min.js:7:9246
>   anonymous/fn@http://admin.xxxxxx.app/scripts/vendors-eb9a79cc0c.js
>   line 14544 > Function:2:258
>   expressionInputWatch@http://admin.xxxxxx.app/scripts/vendors-eb9a79cc0c.js:15673:31
>   $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://admin.xxxxxx.app/scripts/vendors-eb9a79cc0c.js:17216:34
>   $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://admin.xxxxxx.app/scripts/vendors-eb9a79cc0c.js:17491:13
>   tick@http://admin.xxxxxx.app/scripts/vendors-eb9a79cc0c.js:12451:25
>
> vendors...cc0c.js (line 13647) Error: f.selected is undefined

I have no idea what is causing this or how to fix it.
My angularjs version is 1.5.6
ui-router version is 0.3.1

Don't know if it has to do with my code or conflict with another plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see anything wrong with it. Tryed to reproduce your problem with Ui-select 18.1 here: [Reproduction](http://plnkr.co/edit/ezQv2vJDHgBO78hc7MGZ?p=preview) maybe it is the $item component (this worked for me)

```
  <ui-select multiple ng-model="ctrl.address.selected" ng-disabled="disabled">
 <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a person in the list or search his name/age...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
<ui-select-choices repeat="person in ctrl.people | filter: $select.search">
  <div ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
  <small>
    email: {{person.email}}
    age: <span ng-bind-html="''+person.age | highlight: $select.search"></span>
  </small>
</ui-select-choices>
```

Based on the error i think it cannot read the vm.form.roles

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue apparently you are supposed to add the classes "ui-select-choices" and "ui-select-match" otherwise it won't work.